# Esper 5.4 java process High CPU usage

Tags: java, performance, cpu-usage, esper

We have upgraded Esper from 4.9 to 5.4 version. With **Esper 4.9** version we were facing Esper **"out of memory"** issue in our Application. Then we have upgraded Esper to 5.4.

The Esper **"out of memory"** issue has been fixed but now we are facing **High CPU Usage** problem with **Esper 5.4**. Also facing the same problem with **Esper 5.5** version.

We are using Java 8 version in our system.

**Please suggest, How do I investigate:
What part of the application or what thread is causing High CPU Utilization?
And why am I facing high CPU usage problem with Esper latest version.**

Answer (score 0):

It may be the garbage collector that is causing the high CPU. Monitor the heap memory? If the heap gets too tight the garbage collector kicks in often and uses high CPU. Reduce memory use by designing EPL statements smartly. The Esper documentation has tips on memory use. Post your EPL here. Depending on the EPL and the events being processing, Esper engine uses either no memory or can use a lot of memory.

Comment: I have monitored the Heap memory, it seems to be fine. The CPU usage goes high when we create pressure on Esper engine. But it doesn't drop even after the process is completed.

Comment: Provide the EPL here. Also perhaps "completed" means time still passes and there is work to do. Depending on the EPL.